# How to take NiFi UI code in IDE and Build as there is coupled tightly with other modules

Tags: apache-nifi, hdf

How to take NiFi UI code in IDE(Eclipse) and Build, as there is coupled tightly with other modules. In which module the UI related things are present and how to build.

I found that https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/ea9b0db2f620526c8dd0db595cf8b44c3ef835be/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web is the place where UI related codes are present. If this is the correct path then how can I import and build.

Answer (score 2):

As you have found, the nifi-web module is part of nifi-framework, and nifi-framework is packaged as a NAR which is deployed to NiFi's lib directory.

The general process would be...

1. Modify code in nifi-web
2. Run mvn clean package or install on nifi-framework-bundle
3. Copy `nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework-nar/targer/nifi-framework-nar-<version>.nar` to the lib directory of wherever you are running the application from, typically this would be something like `nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT`

I can't speak to anything about Eclipse, but in Intellij you just import all modules from the root pom.